# How to connect and send data to MQ with java

Tags: java, jms, mq

I've run ActiveMQ in my machine (imqbrokerd.exe) and got below details. I've hidden my machine name with

```
[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.788+0530|WARNING|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadNa
me=main;|[S2004]: Log output channel com.sun.messaging.jmq.util.log.SysLogHandle
r is disabled: no imqutil in java.library.path|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.804+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|
================================================================================

Message Queue 5.1
Oracle
Version:  5.1  (Build 9-b)
Compile:  July 29 2014 1229

Copyright (c) 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
================================================================================

Java Runtime: 1.7.0_40 Oracle Corporation C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.819+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|   IMQ_HOME=C:\MessageQueue5.1\mq
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.819+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|IMQ_VARHOME=C:\MessageQueue5.1\var\mq
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.819+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|Windows 7 6.1 x86 <MachineName> (4 cpu) 

|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.835+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|Java Heap Size: max=190080k, current=15872k
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.835+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|Arguments:
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.850+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|[B1060]: Loading persistent data...
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:06.866+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|Using built-in file-based persistent store: C:\MessageQueue5.1\var\mq\ins
tances\imqbroker\
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:07.194+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|[B1270]: Processing messages from transaction log file...
|#]


[#|2015-10-01T19:16:07.396+0530|FORCE|5.1|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName
=main;|[B1039]: Broker "imqbroker@<MachineName>:7676"
ready.
|#]
```

And I'm using below java program to connect to this queue.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class QueueSendLinear {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws JMSException, NamingException {
         // Defines the JNDI context factory.
         final String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";

         // Defines the JMS context factory.
         final String JMS_FACTORY="jms/TestConnectionFactory";

         // Defines the queue.
         final String QUEUE="jms/TestJMSQueue";

         QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
         QueueConnection qcon;
         QueueSession qsession;
         QueueSender qsender;
         Queue queue;
         TextMessage msg;
         String xml = "Sample XML comes here!! ";

         String url = "t3://<MachineName>:7676";
         Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
         env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
         env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
         InitialContext ic =  new InitialContext(env);

         qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
         qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
         qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         queue = (Queue) ic.lookup(QUEUE);
         qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);
         msg = qsession.createTextMessage();
         qcon.start();
         msg.setText(xml);
         qsender.send(msg);
         qsender.close();
         qsession.close();
         qcon.close();

    }

}
```

question here...

a. What should be the values in JNDI_FACTORY, JMS_FACTORY, QUEUE, url  and what do they signify?
b. What does 't3://' in url means? Is this a protocol ? if so, what should be given for active MQ?

FYI, i'm getting below error

```
Oct 01, 2015 7:20:58 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL badAddress
WARNING: "IOP00110603: (BAD_PARAM) Bad host address in -ORBInitDef"
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 603  completed: No
```

[UPDATE #1]:

When I use below code, I get below error. I've attached images of my activeMQ queue details. I know that the URL that i'm using is wrong. Can you please help me out with the right one?

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Couldn't connect to the specified host :  [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208 completed: Maybe]
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.wrapNamingException(Utils.java:83)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReferenceWithRetry(ORBHelper.java:656)

final String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
final String JMS_FACTORY="jms/?";
final String QUEUE = "mq.sys.dmq"; 
QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
QueueConnection qcon;
QueueSession qsession;
QueueSender qsender;
Queue queue;
TextMessage msg;
String xml = "Sample XML comes here!! ";
String url =  "t3://localhost:51010";
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
InitialContext ic =  new InitialContext(env);
qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
queue = (Queue) ic.lookup(QUEUE);
qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);
msg = qsession.createTextMessage();
qcon.start();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look on the ActiveMQ documentation http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html. `t3://` is a proprietary protocol from Oracle (invented originally by Bea). To use it you need to use the Weblogic client library. It cannot be used to communicate to a ActiveMQ broker.

Comment: Thanks @SubOptimal. That page does have some really good info i was looking for.

Comment: What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @SubOptimal landed with some errors and have updated the details in original post.. any help bro?

Comment: Maybe one of those links brings some more light. http://activemq.apache.org/weblogic-integration.html and https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/76268-5892039439047229444

Comment: Thank you @SubOptimal. Got it working :)

Comment: For others which might land in the future on this thread, would you please update your question whith what you had to change to get it finally working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this Helps..
I have passed the JMS server name as an argument. And WLS library jar should be imported

```
private static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAME ="connection factory name goes here";  

private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "Topic Name goes here";


private static final String SERVER_URL_PREFIX = "t3://";
private static final String SERVER_URL_SUFFIX = ".url.com:port";
private static final String USER = "";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";

private static final String LOCAL_DIRECTORY = "C:\\tmp\\poslog\\";


public static void main(String args[]) throws JMSException,
        NamingException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("start" + new Date());
    // INITIALIZE
    System.out.println("creating context for " + args[0]);
    Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVER_URL_PREFIX + args[0] +      SERVER_URL_SUFFIX);
//properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, USER);
//properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, PASSWORD);
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
    TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx
            .lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAME);
    TopicConnection connection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
    TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(false, 0);
    Topic topic = (Topic) ctx.lookup(TOPIC_NAME);
    TopicPublisher sender = session.createPublisher(topic);
```

Comment: first of all, sorry about the long gap. I just picked this up back and crash-landed quickly with another error. I've updated the original post and need your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

JNDI_FACTORY is more like a driver that you want to use to connect, they are usually specific to the vendor in your case is weblogic and is pre-defined.

JMS_FACTORY is the connection factory that you have already predefined in web logic for this type of integration. it is responsible for managing the connections to the queue.

QUEUE also is something that you need to predefine / setup on weblogic admin console. It is the reference to the queues that reside on weblogic which you have setup before hand.

t3 is the connection type you are using, the other alternative could be iiop. t3 it is a more lightweight type of connection.